# Playing a song in DIRECTORY_MUSIC

Tags: android

I saved a file into the music directory using this:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, "SpaceJam.mp3");
```

In my main activity, I'd now like to access it and play it.

How do I retrieve the information of the song so that I can use it with:

```
mp.setDataSource(??);
```

"mp" being the name of my MediaPlayer. Thanks.

Comment: send More What error u found and which sdcard u save file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098001/playing-audio-files-in-a-directory-of-sdcard-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
     File file = new File(path, "Hunny.mp3");
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(file.toString());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if you have *External Storage*:

```
 File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
 File file = new File(path, "SpaceJam.mp3");

....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
File file = new File(path, "SpaceJam.mp3");
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

EDIT:

```
mp.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: You get an error on 'mp.setDataSource(file);' that setDataSource is expecting a string, not a file.